# Saving Child Terms on front end not setting parent

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-meta, front-end, terms

I recently had a issue where I was trying to save the child terms on a front end post form. [ORIGINAL POST AND CODE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283342/front-end-post-save-child-terms)

I thought I had it good to go but now I just realize it's not setting the parent term as well, just the child term.

```
    $nhb_type_value = $_POST['nhb'];

    $nhb_type = wp_get_object_terms($Property_Id, 'city-type', array('fields' => 'ids'));
    $nhb_type = array_reverse($nhb_type);
                    if (!empty($nhb_type)) {
                        $terms = get_term($nhb_type[0], 'city-type');
                        $nhb_type_value = $terms->slug;
                    }

$city_type = wp_get_object_terms($Property_Id, 'city-type', array('fields' => 'ids'));
$city_type = array_reverse($city_type);
        if (!empty($city_type)) {
            $city_term = get_term($city_type[0], 'city-type');
            $city_type_value = $city_term->slug;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the parent as well. you can loop on all the posts and check if the post terms have a parent and then append him. wordpress don't auto set the parent term even in the admin.

Comment: I dont get what you mean?

Comment: I meant if you want now to change all the posts that already posted you can loop on all over the posts and append the parent term. for new posts you need to add to the `wp_set_object_terms` the parent as well.

Comment: How would I add it though to set object terms if In my question and my original post, I've tried doing so, thats what $city_type is

Comment: see the answer its will help you to understand the process and to fix your old code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix all the older posts that you already posted with only the child term.
You need run this function only 1 time and its will add you the parents terms. its for all the ancestors of the child term.

**Make sure to backup the DB before you run this function.**

```
function fix_terms_parents() {
    /**
     * Create a query that select all the posts in your post type
     */
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'property', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    if ( $query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            /**
             * Get all the terms that set to the post
             */
            $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'city-type');
            foreach($terms as $term) {
                /**
                 * Get the term ancestors and append them
                 */
                $ancestors = get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'city-type');
                if($ancestors) {
                    $new_terms = wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $ancestors, 'city-type', true);
                    // the $new_terms variable is array of all the new terms that you set
                }
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Here is a function to set all the term ancestors. you can use with the return that you get from `wp_set_object_terms` in your old code.

```
/**
 * @param int $post_id the post id
 * @param string $taxonomy
 * @param array terms ids
 *
 * @return array of the ancestors terms that was append
 */
function set_ancestors_terms($post_id, $taxonomy, $terms) {
    foreach($terms as $term_id) {
        $ancestors = get_ancestors($term_id, $taxonomy);
        if($ancestors) {
            // Append parent terms
            return wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $ancestors, $taxonomy, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The first function you need to run only 1 time put it in the function.php and add `add_action( 'init', 'fix_terms_parents', 10);` too before it to run it. 
After this you can delete this function its only to fix the old posts.

Before you run the first function create DB backup.

The Second function you add too to the functions.php and you run it in your old code when you set the terms you need to get the return like this and run the function.

```
$terms_array = wp_set_object_terms($pid, $nhb_type_value, 'city-type');
set_ancestors_terms($pid, 'city-type', $terms_array);
```

Comment: Both codes I put in functions as is and then what? The parent terms will set on the front end post forms?

Comment: see the answer.. I edit it with some explanation.

Comment: Ok i got the first code working thanks, soon as i figure out the second one I'll accept the answer.

Comment: The second one is for your old code edit your question and add the code that you have with the function `wp_set_object_terms()`

Comment: The parent terms are only set when the second dropdown (child terms) are selected/set. Any way to make it so that the parent terms can be set if the child terms arent? @shibi

Comment: What do you mean? How can you set the parent if you dont know who is the child?

Comment: On my page there's 2 dropdowns - 1. the parent -- "City" and 2. the child terms --  "Neighborhoods" ....  If I try to only choose the city without choosing the neighborhood then the city (parent) doesn't get set.

Comment: Add the code to the question

Comment: What you mean? It's the same code you helped me with

Comment: Its not really related to this question. The problem probably thats you just don't use the `wp_se_object_terms` for the parent dropdown but I need to see code in order to try to help you.